# What are the correct settings for exporting rigs and meshes (FBX) from Blender 3 to Unreal Engine?

Tags: export, .fbx, unreal-engine

Every setting I try seems to have some issue when importing to Unreal.
The main one being that the root bone is scaled 100 times when importing to Unreal, even though scale is 1 in Blender. I tried playing with the units settings but I can't figure it out, it seems that no matther the settings something is always scaled wrong (either scaled 100 times or not scaled 100 times but with a 100th of the size in the scene).

Other things I would like to know the correct settings: which axis should I select as forward and up? Should I select what UNREAL considers to be forward and up, or should I select what my model's forward and up are in the Blender file?

What should I select as the bones' primary axis and secondary axis?

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Change the Unit scale to 0.1

It's a weird setup but it works

Not so sure about the other settings I'm afraid, its been a while since I had to do this

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work. At least not with a rigged mesh. What should be the settings in the FBX export window?

Comment: I would have thought X forward and Z up should be the exported settings, I do remember having all sorts of difficulty with it at the time.

Comment: Don't know whether [this YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZf74m2YFpw) gives you the information you need?

Comment: There's another tutorial which has been linked on BlenderNation daily news letter today which specifically mentions fixing root scale in the description [here](https://www.blendernation.com/2022/04/30/correctly-exporting-characters-from-blender-to-unreal-engine-5/?utm_source=newsletter-1762&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=BlenderNation-daily)